# Migration issue with opentelemetry-api from 0.5.0 to 0.8.0

Tags: java, scala, open-telemetry

I am facing this issue when upgrading **opentelemetry-api** from **0.5.0** to **0.8.0**.

Consider the following code snippet,

```
import io.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetry
import io.opentelemetry.context.Scope
import io.opentelemetry.trace._

object Main4 extends App {

  val a: Tracer = OpenTelemetry.getTracer(getClass.getSimpleName)
  val b: Span = a.spanBuilder("test").startSpan()
  val c: Scope = a.withSpan(b)
  try {
    val d: Span = TracingContextUtils.getCurrentSpan
    val e: SpanContext = d.getContext
    val f: Span = DefaultSpan.getInvalid
    val g: SpanContext = f.getContext
    println(d)
    println(e)
    println(e.isValid)
    println(e.getSpanId)
    println(e.getTraceId)

    println()
    println()
    println()

    println(f)
    println(g)
    println(g.isValid)
    println(g.getSpanId)
    println(g.getTraceId)

    println()
    println()

    println(d == f)

  } finally {
    c.close()
  }
}
```

With **0.5.0**, I am getting the output as: -

```
DefaultSpan
SpanContext{traceId=TraceId{traceId=f153124023eeab63d027ca493e05cbdf}, spanId=SpanId{spanId=fb8136024af9a4ae}, traceFlags=TraceFlags{sampled=false}, traceState=TraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false}
true
SpanId{spanId=fb8136024af9a4ae}
TraceId{traceId=f153124023eeab63d027ca493e05cbdf}



DefaultSpan
SpanContext{traceId=TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}, spanId=SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}, traceFlags=TraceFlags{sampled=false}, traceState=TraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false}
false
SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}
TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}


false
```

with **0.8.0**, I am getting the output as: -

```
DefaultSpan
SpanContext{traceId=TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}, spanId=SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}, traceFlags=TraceFlags{sampled=false}, traceState=TraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false}
false
SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}
TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}



DefaultSpan
SpanContext{traceId=TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}, spanId=SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}, traceFlags=TraceFlags{sampled=false}, traceState=TraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false}
false
SpanId{spanId=0000000000000000}
TraceId{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000}


true
```

I think with **0.8.0** there is something missing in my code due to which it is not being correctly working as expected.

Can someone let me know what changes I need to do with my code so as to obtain the proper **Span** and not invalid **Span** as I am getting with **0.5.0**?

Note:- I am using:- **scala** -> 2.13.3, **jvm** -> 14, **sbt** -> 1.3.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.8.0, the API no longer generates spans in the absence of an installed SDK. This was done primarily for performance reasons, so that the API itself will operate at lower overhead when there is no SDK installed.

If you want valid spans, just add the SDK to your classpath, and you will get them back.

Comment: As you answered, I have done the same and the issue got resolved but soon after that I am started facing another issue:- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882708/spancontext-createfromremoteparent-not-working-properly-with-opentelemetry-sdk-0

Can you just help me with this also?